# Add xml-stylesheet processing instruction just before root element

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I have an XML document that is generated from database information. I also have a separate XMLT file. I need to use VB.NET to insert the XSL link into the XML document. I am getting it inserted, but it's inserting into the wrong place. I need it in the header but it's putting it after the root node.

Here's the code I'm using to insert the xml-stylsheet processing instruction:

```
Dim fiFilePath As String = Me.CSFileName
Dim xmlCs As XmlDocument = Nothing
Try
    xmlCs = New XmlDocument()
    xmlCs.Load(fiFilePath)
    ' update the XSLT path as per the 'newStyleSheetPath' argument
    xmlCs.DocumentElement.PrependChild(xmlCs.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", String.Format("type={0}text/xsl{1} href={2}{3}{4}", Chr(34), Chr(34), Chr(34), newStylesheetPath, Chr(34))))
    'Save the created document
    xmlCs.Save(fiFilePath)
Catch ex As Exception
    xmlCs = Nothing
    fiFilePath = Nothing
    Throw ex
End Try
```

This is what that code is outputting:

```
<DocumentRoot>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="APSCS.xsl"?>
  <realmCode code="US" />
```

But it needs to be:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="APSCS.xsl"?>
<DocumentRoot>
  <realmCode code="US" />
```

This is all part of an export where the XSLT is packaged with the XML, so if someone opens the XML, it appears in the browser using the XSLT file sent with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
xmlCs.InsertBefore(xmlCs.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", String.Format("type={0}text/xsl{1} href={2}{3}{4}", Chr(34), Chr(34), Chr(34), newStylesheetPath, Chr(34))), xmlCs.DocumentElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing the concept of the *root node* with that of the *document element*.  The *root node* is the node that contains all other nodes.  It is a hidden, unnamed node.  Take your stated, desired output as an example:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="APSCS.xsl"?>
<DocumentRoot>
    <realmCode code="US" />
</DocumentRoot>
```

In that XML document, both the `DocumentRoot` element and the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction are children of the *root node*.  The *document element* is something different.  In each XML document, there can be no more than one element that is a child of the root node.  In other words, something like this is **not** well formed:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="APSCS.xsl"?>
<DocumentRoot1>
    <realmCode code="US" />
</DocumentRoot1>
<DocumentRoot2>
    <realmCode code="US" />
</DocumentRoot2>
```

Since you can only have one root-level element, that element is referred to as the *document element*.  So, when you say that you want to add a child to the document element, it will not add it as a child to the root node.  Rather, it will add it as a child to the document element which, in your example, is `DocumentRoot`.

The `XmlDocument` object is, itself, a reference to the root element.  So, to add a child at the root level, you would need to do it like this:

```
xmlCs.AppendChild(...)  ' Adds child at the root level
xmlCs.DocumentElement.AppendChild(...)  ' Adds child under the DocumentRoot element
```

To get the processing instruction to be added just before the `DocumentRoot` element, you can use the `InsertBefore` method, like this:

```
xmlCs.InsertBefore(xmlCs.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", String.Format("type={0}text/xsl{1} href={2}{3}{4}", Chr(34), Chr(34), Chr(34), newStylesheetPath, Chr(34))), xmlCs.DocumentElement)
```